# Google Apps migration for free (legacy Google Apps accounts)

Tags: google-workspace

I was looking at the [Google Apps migration tool](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6003169?hl=en) today.

The accounts I want to migrate between are 2 existing Google Apps accounts (both free version singed up to pre 2012).

But when I follow the instructions on the Google migration site, I can’t find the migration tool from the dashboard—is it only available to paid accounts?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not available for free legacy Google Apps accounts.

[Source: Google Support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6043385)

You probably already found the answer, but since it took me a while, I figured I would leave it here for the next person...